# Getting empty Array after req.logIn() in passport login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, passport.js

I am facing a strange behavior where I am trying to make two type of login, One with password and other is as Guest. Passport req.logIn() working fine in case of User login with password. But when I am login through guest it set empty Array in session.

Let me show you what details  I am giving passport for storing the data.

In case of Registered user

```
var User = [];
User['email'] = "email@domain.com";
User['id_customer'] = "1";
User['id_user'] = "1";
User['other_info'] = "xyz";
User['other_info'] = "xyz";
User['other_info'] = "xyz";
User['other_info'] = "xyz";
```

Now in case of Guest User

```
var User = [];
User['email'] = "email@domain.com";
User['id_guest'] = "1";
User['other_info'] = "xyz";
```

Passport login ie `req.logIn()` is

```
req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                if(err instanceof Error) {
                    sails.log.debug(err.stack);
                } else
                {
                    sails.log.debug(err);
                }
                res.redirect('index/error');
            }


            if (req.xhr) {
              return res.send({
                "success": 1,
                "message": info.message,
                "user": user
              });
            } else {
                res.redirect('/');
            }

          });
```

I am not able to debug why exactly passport do not serializing my Guest user info in right way. Is there any constraint in serializing.

Let me show you my serialize and deserialize methods.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  //  saving Complete User Object in session CouchBase instead of saving
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  //  Getting complete User Object from Couchbase as placed in req for each request
  done(null, user);
});
```

Comment: add more info like how show your settings to configure sessions on your framework

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I was making a mistake

I replaced `var User = [];` with `var User = {};` and it worked.